# Can the current (08/2011) 27" iMac support two extra screens without additional hardware?

Tags: imac, display

I am currently considering a new iMac, but I was wondering if this would be able to support two extra monitors.

The setup I am considering:

- iMac built-in 27" monitor.
- Current Dell 27" monitor @ 2650x1440 (Dual-link DVI via adapter)
- One of the Thunderbolt displays @ 2560x1440 (via one of the two thunderbolt ports)

This is really two related questions:

- Is the above setup viable at all?
- Will the available resolution be restricted by the video card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can. Here is an example of a 27" iMac with two 30" Dell displays. 
http://www.engadget.com/2011/05/03/apple-imac-hands-on-with-dual-30-inch-displays-video/